# Understanding すっげー時間のムダ ホント 金 返せって感じ

Tags: translation

From the first episode of Death Note:

> すっげー時間のムダ ホント 金 返せって感じ

**Questions:**

1. Since 時間のムダ, ホント, and 金 are all nouns or noun phrases, why are none of them marked with particles?
2. What is the literal the meaning of this sentence? My best guess is something like

> The feeling of "Serious waste of time, return my money!"

But it's hard to follow without the inclusion of particles.

Comment: Was it really rendered as one line like that?

Comment: It appears to be so, yeah (from the subtitles I have).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would read it as two lines like this.

> すっげー時間のムダ。
> ホント、金返せって感じ。

ホント is used as an adverb. You could say 本当に but it would probably sound too formal in this context.

The particle を is omitted between 金 and 返せ. This happens all the time in informal speech.

Comment: Is the first sentence also lacking a だ/です (also omitted due to it being informal speech)? Or is it more like an interjection (e.g., "Such a waste!", which strictly speaking isn't required to be a complete sentence, at least in English anyway).

Comment: @George - Yes, and the second, too.

Answer (score 3):

Did you have the impression that all noun phrases must be marked with particles? This isn't the case, particularly in spoken Japanese.

Also, normally in written Japanese you don't have spaces like this. I think this must be due to how the subtitles are written to reflect the rhythm of the dialogue.

The idiomatic (not literal) translation would be something like:

> すっげー時間のムダ ホント 金 返せって感じ
>
> What a frigging waste of time, honestly. I'm like, give me my money back.

Comment: Are there particles implicitly present in the sentence (appended to one or more of these nouns), but omitted (due to informal speech)?